# Open Url with post Method android

Tags: java, android

I have to send some parameters to a url and open it, But i dont know how to do it

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.param1 = "param1";
variables.param2 = "param2";

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");                 
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = variables;
navigateToURL(request,"_blank");
```

This is an example in IOS but i dont know how to do it in android

i Think i have to do it with an intent but

```
params = URLEncoder.encode(""+ "cmd=param1"+ "&business=param2"+"utf-8");

String url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" + params;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

startActivity(browserIntent);
```

i think i should do it like this but it is not working
i am sending it to paypal

Comment: try using HttpClient with name value pairs

Comment: but i have to open it in the android browser, how i do that

Comment: You are totally wrong in your java approach

Comment: I know IOS is different but, the IOS is usign a Post Method, the thing is, how do i add params to the url and open it, is there some method equivalent or a way ? Do i have to use a type of Post method ?

Answer (score 4):

this is what i was looking for

```
        String uri = Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("param1", "param1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("param2", "parma2")
                    .build().toString();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Awesome!! you save my life!