# After opening Paypal page in Web View ,cross button click and pay with paypal button not work in android?

Tags: android, paypal, android-webview

I am Using Web View to open paypal page for payment gatways . i am sending data with url just like GET Methods, and page is open successfully but it's not working
we couldn't click on pay with paypal button and cross sign to cancel the payments.
I searched a lot but didn't get any proper answer.it is quiet important for me.

Here is my code for web View .

```
public class PayPalWebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;
String urls,intent_value,paypalId,paymentStatus,cancelPayment,currencyCode,country,cmd,title,language,
        fn,ln,city,st,zp,add1,add2,bookig_id,pck_id,pck_title,user_id,total,postData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal_web_view);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_paypal);


    paypalId = "info@guideturbo.com";

    paymentStatus = "http://www.guideturbo.com/payments/payment_status";

    cancelPayment = "http://www.guideturbo.com/payments/payment_status";

    currencyCode = "USD";

    country = "USA";

    cmd = "_xclick";

    title = "Ms";

    language = "EN";

    try {

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        bookig_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("booking_id");
        pck_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("package_id");
        pck_title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        total = getIntent().getStringExtra("total");
        fn = getIntent().getStringExtra("fn");
        ln = getIntent().getStringExtra("ln");
        city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
        st = getIntent().getStringExtra("state");
        add1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("add1");
        add2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("add2");
        zp = getIntent().getStringExtra("zp");
        user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");

    }

 total = total.replace("$","");

        urls = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"+"business="+paypalId +"&"+"return="+paymentStatus +"&"+"cancel_return="+cancelPayment +"&"
                +"language="+language +"&"+"title="+title +"&"+"first_name="+fn +"&"+"last_name="+ln +"&"+"country="+country +"&"
                +"cmd="+cmd +"&"+"amount="+total +"&"+"custom="+bookig_id +"&"+"item_name="+pck_title +"&"+"package_id="+pck_id +"&"
                +"user_id="+user_id +"&"+"currency_code="+currencyCode +"&"+"address1="+add1 +"&"+"address2="+add2 +"&"+"city="+city +"&"
 +"state="+st +"&"+"zip="+zp;
 }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(urls);
}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        /*view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;*/
        if(url.contains(urls)){
            //do something
            view.loadUrl(urls);
        }
        return true;
    }
       }
 }
```

My issue is that Paypal page open but nothing is open after clicking pay with paypal button and cancel page url redirection which is provided is not working .
Kindly suggest some solution so that i can continue ..

Comment: Hi can anyone suggest me what to do ?

Comment: Why not just open a new page, get rid of webview?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24496263/3634867